# What Kind of weapon would create a scar like this?

Tags: weapons, writing

Does anyone know what kind of weapon could make a jagged scar from the middle of your shoulder to just where your wrist starts?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding alexandra, this is a site for asking for help creating fictional worlds, it's difficult to tell at the moment what your question might have to do with that. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up inn the [help] about how we work. You'll then be able to [edit] your question to make clear a) Worldbuilding context, b) how your question relates to that. Enjoy the site.

Comment: Is the scar inflicted in battle? Is it a result of torture? Could it be an accidental weapon injury - maybe self-inflicted through carelessness?  Could it be as a result of the person having to free themselves  from a trap by cutting their own arm in some way? Could it even be deliberate self-harm for psychological reasons? Please give some background so that we can answer more easily. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Does a lion's claw count as a weapon? That would definitely do it - no problem.

Comment: Barbed wire....

Comment: touching socket with wet hand or swimming with jellyfish ;D

Comment: Is it a burn mark perhaps?

Comment: blade, nail, shrapnel, wire fence, apple tree, wild dog, parachuting accident, botched bone marrow transplant operation, short-changed ho, disintegrating subatomic enfomulator, and many,many,many,many more. Really, you are asking "what makes a cut"?

Comment: Why is there a vote to reopen? The question hasn't been edited to clarify as of yet. There's no worldbuilding context and, as written, is too broad. VTLC. Alexandra, you have an interesting *basis* for a question, but it needs a lot of work.

Answer (score 4):

**Anything with a hook**

It gets dragged down the arm and the hook stops it getting free.

[image][image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I actually have something similar, irl. A scar that goes from my wrist to my armpit. My dog was running at me from across the field, with her collar on that had 2cm spikes all over it. I don't know why I tried to catch/stop her as she darted past me at full speed, but it ripped a nice deep gash that was both jagged AND resembling a perforated line in parts, where it caught on the skin and 'jumped' a few cm's to the next bit.

Rolling that around from the armpit to the shoulder could be as simple as having your character losing his balance and tumbling in a backwards somersault. With the right fall physics you could probably even drag that down from the shoulder to the ankle, and have a scar that runs from wrist to ankle.

Answer (score 3):

### **The weapon of the gods - lightning!**

Some of the most spectacular (and amazingly shaped) scars are caused by lightning. They are certainly jagged but surprisingly not deep in some cases. Just look at some of  [these images](https://www.boredpanda.com/scars-after-surviving-lightning-strike-lichtenberg-figures-photos/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organic)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To me, an injury this long and along a limb would most likely be inflicted by accident. Some possible scenarios:

- The person stuck their arm somewhere they shouldn't like into a deep hole and when yanking it out quickly (maybe a creature in the hole bit them), they scrape their entire arm on a sharp protrusion
- The person tanked a fireball or electrical attack by covering their face with their arm leaving the side facing the attack to be burned.  If you want a more distinct scar, maybe they were wearing armor and the burn only got through at the seams
- The person had damaged armor violently removed. Maybe they were hit in the shoulder with an arrow and then their entire sleeve with arrowhead still stuck in it scraped along their arm
- Similar to my first suggestion, maybe they got their arm caught in a large beast's mouth and cut themselves on its teeth

Comment: Good ideas, although the question is "What kind of *weapon*?"

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica 1. A sharp rock, 2. A magical staff, 3. An arrowhead, 4. A tooth

Comment: Okay, but my first thought was that a sharp rock that is part of a hole, isn't actually a weapon - unless of course this is a sentient hole ;-)